# Building wheel for reportlab (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, macos, setup.py

I am trying to run a requirements.txt file that happens to have ReportLab as a dependency but I have not been successful. I have tried `pip install reportlab` but the version that is installed doesn't seem to work with the other dependencies. I have used `pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache` as well as appending -vvv on that command but I still haven't been successful. Any help with this?

```
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DRENDERPM_FT -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.21" -Isrc/rl_addons/renderPM -Isrc/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -Isrc/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-dict.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-dict.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DRENDERPM_FT -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.21" -Isrc/rl_addons/renderPM -Isrc/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -Isrc/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.o
    src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:100:9: error: implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char *)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      len = strlen (s);
            ^
    src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:100:9: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strlen'
    src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:102:3: error: implicitly declaring library function 'memcpy' with type 'void *(void *, const void *, unsigned long)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      memcpy (new, s, len);
      ^
    src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:102:3: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'memcpy'
    src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:172:10: error: implicitly declaring library function 'strcmp' with type 'int (const char *, const char *)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if (!strcmp (nc->table[i & mask].name, name))
             ^
    src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:172:10: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strcmp'
    3 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/c0/p5ztz03d7yg8_hqxl6pfpskw0000gn/T/pip-install-xaveou5b/reportlab_a0c7466f687c456b8cf242c9beaeb10b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/c0/p5ztz03d7yg8_hqxl6pfpskw0000gn/T/pip-install-xaveou5b/reportlab_a0c7466f687c456b8cf242c9beaeb10b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/c0/p5ztz03d7yg8_hqxl6pfpskw0000gn/T/pip-record-oqkx2tig/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/evapn/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/reportlab Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Although I didn't get a Traceback for this particular error, I have added some more text from the error for context. I hope it's sufficient and can get me some help.